# Strange result using grep

Tags: sh

I've made a small script trying to search through a file looking for all occurrences of specific strings like this: a0002 b0590 c0964

The script goes like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
#include <stdio.h>
#
while read id; 
 do      
    awk {'print $1'} test.trans | grep -e "$id"
 done < test.id
```

To simplify things, I made a stripped down version of the file I'm searching through (test.trans):

```
"a0001"
"a0002"
"b0586"
"b0587"
"b0588"
"b0589"
"b0590"
"b0591"
"b0852"
"b0952"
"a0002"
"b0587"
"c0952"
"c0964"
"c1783"
"c1786"
"c1787"
```

I have stored all the relevant search strings in a separate file named test.id which looks like this:

```
a0002
b0587
b0588
b0589
b0590
b0591
b0852
b0952
c0952
c0964
c1781
```

The idea is to pass each search string in the test.id file as a variable which is then used by grep to filter out all occurrences in the test.trans file
However, when I run the script, grep only matches some of the strings. When I change the order of the search patterns in the test.id file, the result also changes. What am I doing wrong?
I consider myself a newbie in shell programming, and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Is each of your search terms in trans.id on a separate line?

Comment: which grep on which os?

Comment: Each search term is on a separate line and I'm using standard grep on OS X

Comment: do you have a problem with the test.trans and test.id file you show us in your post? If so, what is the result of the script?

Comment: Yes, I had a problem with the test.id file which was received from a DOS machine. See my comment below.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the reason for your problem.
But here are some remarks that don't fit in a comment.

1. If you want to put out a file to stdout (the standard output) you can use `cat test.trans` instead of `awk {'print $1'} test.trans`.
2. But is you want grep to process a file you must not read it with some other tool and pipr it to grep. grep can read this file directly by using `grep -e "$id" test.trans
3. If you alread use `awk` you don't need grep. you can achiefe this wih awk by calling `awk /"$id"'/ {print $1}' test.trans`  grep can filter more than one pattern. Instead of your for loop do

   ```
   grep -f test.id test.trans
   ```

Comment: Using just  awk /"$id"'/ {print $1}' test.trans.txt  seemed to help a bit (found 1 more string), but it still can't find 4 of the strings (b0589 c1783 c1786 c1787)

Comment: I guess I need to use awk because I want to print out certain fields in the original file (part_1.trans) of which test.trans is a simplified version

Answer (score 0):

After some experimenting, I found out that it all boiled down to removing the carriage return (\r) from each line in the test.id file. This file was received from a DOS-machine, and my iMac is using UNIX-format which only contains newline (\n)